# click event is not working.How can I remove the arrow besde app name? and, sliding tabs are working but when I click on any tab(tab1/tab2/tab3) why?

Tags: android

How can I remove the arrow beside app name? Also, my sliding tabs are working but when I click on any tab (tab1/tab2/tab3) the click event is not working. Why?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {R.drawable.ic_action_home,
            R.drawable.ic_action_categories,
            R.drawable.ic_action_notification,
            R.drawable.ic_action_profile};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.my_tab_title);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);


        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.Viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);


        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }
    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(3).setIcon(tabIcons[3]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFragment(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        adapter.addFragment(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
        adapter.addFragment(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();


        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); is why you're having the backbutton. and what do you mean by click isn't working on tab?

Comment: i am not able to click on a particular tab, but i can swipe between the tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the removal of the navigation-up button just remove the line:

getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this code to enable changes when tabs are selected:

```
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

Also, as suggested by others above, just remove the line below to hide back arrow:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This is what I believe is missing from your code above; good luck!

Comment: thanks Eenvincible, that back navigation arrow solution just worked, but still having problem on clicking tabs.